# remove AppDelegate's observer in other ViewController

Tags: ios, object, nsnotificationcenter

The NSNotification observer is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(newShipCome:) name:kNewShipNotifaction object:nil];
```

I would like to remove observer in another ViewController.

I've done this in one of my ViewController

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:[UIApplication sharedApplication] name:kNewShipNotifaction object:nil];
```

but still not work. Do anyone know how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove observer of AppDelegate, you are passing incorrect object in `removeObserver:` method.

Instead of :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:[UIApplication sharedApplication] name:kNewShipNotifaction object:nil];
```

Use:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] name:kNewShipNotifaction object:nil];
```

Comment: Hi Midhun, do you know how to remove observer from other ViewController? OtherViewController *vc = [[OtherViewController alloc]init];     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:vc name:@"test" object:nil]; didn't really remove observer.

Comment: No, it won't work. You are creating a new object there. If you want to removeObserver from the same class pass self instead of that vc variable

Comment: So do I have a chance to remove otherViewController's observer?

Comment: @Jenny Say, you are in Class A and need to remove Class B's observer. Then you need to pass B's object to Class A. If you are in Class A and need to remove it's observer you can pass self to that removeObserver:

Comment: I guess singleton is the way to pass same object to another ViewController, right?

Comment: @Jenny: There is many ways to do so, you can share it via AppDelegate (it's a singleton), you can pass the object directly to secondviewcontroller by declaring a it's property in firstclass

Comment: @Jenny : I am having similar kind of problem. Can you please help me how you solved that

Comment: @MidhunMP your answer really helped me. Thanks a lot